# Get value of pre-populated Gravity forms field as variable in my function

Tags: functions, plugin-gravity-forms, query-string

I am using a dynamic field in Gravity forms which is pre-populated via a query string from another page.

```
https://www.domain.com/example?country=US
```

I have a function where I would like to get the value of the pre-populated field as follows:

```
function subswitch_text_shortcode() {
    return $country = [GET GRAVITY FORMS FIELD VALUE];
    switch($country){
      case "UK":
        return "UK address.";
        break;
      case "US":
        return "US address.";
        break;
      default:
        return '';
        break;
      };
}
```

How could I retrieve this?

Comment: You mean like `$country = $_GET['country'];` ?

Comment: yes but in the end I think I will just go with your suggestion and avoid gravity forms completely.